What are those small notes below other ones?

When I search for "tiny notes" in the Internet, it says to me "appoggiature".  But they are placed just before the main note, not immediately below, like in my picture above.
So, what are those small notes?

You're absolutely right that these are not appoggiature.

Piece and composer please! Then we will be much more likely to give you an exact answer. As the one answer below already points out, small notes can be used for quite a few different functions.

Those just look like some weirdness from a piece of notation software. Maybe the slurs made some of the note heads come out wonky.

@NeilMeyer - those slurs are ties!

@user103031 Show us more of the page, please.

One other possibility that @Lazy didn't mention is the notes to be played by other Trumpet players if there are more than one trumpet available, or if there are no players for other instruments in a similar range (such as Cornets, Flugelhorns, or French horns).
Again, as @Lazy is saying, it would have been helpful to provide the composer, the title, and a link to the full score of what could have been an arrangement for brass band / marching band, so we can know from the score what those small notes mean.

This use of small notes is another type of cue note, which Lazy did mention, of course. Lazy did not clarify that sometimes cue notes are included to actually be played in certain situations.

@ToddWilcox Thanks.  The term "cue note" is new to me.

Small notes can have a lot of different meanings. In this case this would most likely be so called cue notes. These are small notes included in usually parts and vocal scores, not to be played by the musician, but to give some context to what the other voices are playing. Usually this is done to facilitate finding the cue, although in this case I suppose they are there to give the group an idea of what the other voices are playing at the same time. That being said, this is the first time I’m encountering this use. Maybe you could share with us what composer, piece and edition this is?
Small notes can also designate grace notes, alternative notes, on polyphonic instruments optional notes, less important notes (e.g. to emphasize the melody) ...

The notes in normal notation are indicating  the Trumpet part (melody)-  while the "tiny notes" contain the harmony, (piano reduction for keyboard accompaniment, or other C-instruments). This kind of score is also useful as C-direction sheet for the bandleader.
"A score (literally and etymologically a set of parts ) is the graphic organization of several contemporary musical lines , for use by the composer or conductor in order to control and manage at a glance the entire simultaneity of the parts that contribute to the musical work."
(Engl. Translation of this Italian Wiki article:
https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitura#

There is a problem with the translation, namely that "score" is not etymologically a set of parts as is Italian partitura.

I get that "C-instruments" means "non-transposing instruments" (I think?) but what is "C-direction" ?

I think that @Albrecht Hügli may mean a conductor's score which is entirely in C (concert pitch) in spite of all (or many) of the instruments being transposing instruments.
In my experience conducting British Brass Bands, the scores usually show the actual written part for the transposing instruments, but one does occasionally get a score which is written in concert pitch (which is a pain if one doesn't have ones transposing head on!)

That's correct. I've later found rhe term "concert pitch'.

No, not appoggiaturas in this case, or any other type of grace note.
This appears to be the top line of a musical score, probably for some sort of band.  It would have been very useful to show us more of it!   But I think we can be sure that the small notes indicate what other instruments are playing, maybe the other trumpet parts. Maybe the first trumpet player directs the band.  In old-style brass bands the conductor, even if not playing themselves, often worked from a fully-cues Solo Cornet part (though I don't think this is quite what is happening here).  Maybe the intention is 'if only one player, play the top notes, if more, fill in the harmony with the others'.
If it was the upper stave of a piece for solo trumpet and piano, I'd expect to see a brace in front of the staves linking it to the stave below.
We're fishing here, with too little information, though!   Perhaps @user103031 could replace the picture with one showing the whole page?
